# ggplot2 with colored borders but without fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a dot plot using library `ggplot2`. My script generates a dot plot for the sample data below, but I am required to have dot border colored but rest of the dot should be empty (no fill). For example if my dots are red, blue and green in color, I would just like to have the dot borders to be red, blue and green, while rest of the dot should be empty.

Following is my current script and sample data

```
library(ggplot2)      
File2=read.table("PB12_combo.txt", header=T, sep="\t")    
ggplot(File2, aes(x_axis, y_axis, colour=factor(z_axis)))+geom_point(size=5)

     x_axis  y_axis  z_axis
       605     250     2
       690     394     2
       762     109     2
       543     495     2
       388     538     2
       758     736     2
       197     409     2
       390     106     3
       390     343     4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the shape for the points to 1

```
ggplot(File2, aes(x_axis, y_axis, colour=factor(z_axis)))+geom_point(size=5,shape=1)
```